# Why doesn't AddForce get added to my rigidbody. C#. Uniity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

What I have is a rigid body with a raycast that's calculating a dot product, in order to determine if it is on a slope. I then use the dot product to determine if the RB is going to overshoot a slope, if it dose then it should get pushed down so its back on the ground. The problem is that the *rb.AddForce* doesn't work, but the *Debug.Log("PUSH DOWN")* gets called correctly.

Any help is appreciated. P.S sorry for my bad English.

```
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, 
                    out slopeOvershoottInfo, rayHitdistance, whatIsGround))
{
      float  dot = Vector3.Dot(new Vector3(velocity.x, 0, velocity.z).normalized, slopeOvershoottInfo.normal);
        
      float roundedDot = Mathf.Round(dot * 1000) / 1000;// i do this because the dot changes large decemel increments even when on an even slope, so i do this to prevent those slite osolations

      if (dot != 0 && roundedDot != oldDot)
      {
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.down * overshootingSlopePushdown, ForceMode.Impulse);
            Debug.Log("PUSH DOWN");
            oldDot = roundedDot;
      }
}
```

Comment: And what is the value of overshootingSlopePushdown?

Comment: Could be several things: 1. using `ForceMode.Impulse` takes the rigidbody's mass into consideration, so you might be adding a very small force. 2. `overshootingSlopePushdown` is too small to make a difference / mass is too high. 3. Going `vector3.down` will basically add forces going down, so it might just bump the rb against the collider beneath it. 4. Probably unlikely, but your rb might be kinematic. 4. you might be overwriting velocity somewhere else in your code

Comment: @BugFinder the value is 2. I have tried to increase to like 10 but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Probably should have added this in the beginning, but when I replaced both of the roundedDot with dot in the if statement, it seemed to push it down, but continuously.